# JSF 2.0 : How to set order of validation error

Tags: jsf, hibernate-validator

I am using Jsf 2 with Hibernate Validator. It works fine, but I don't know how I can set the order of the generated errors.

For an example:

My Managed Bean

```
public class UserPresentation {

@NotNull(message = "EmailNullError")
@Email(message="EmailNotValidError")
String email;

@NotNull(message="passwordNullError")
String password;
//getter,setter...
}
```

In the frontend the passwordNullError appears before the emailNullerror in the generated ul-Tag. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the message labels to your inputs, using the `for` attribute. The validation messages will appear right behind the according inputs.

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.email}" id="email" />
<h:message for="email" />           
<h:inputSecret value="#{myBean.password}" id="password" />
<h:message for="password" />
```

Comment: My design requires a single message component.  Is there any other solution to this?