# Validator error ordering

Tags: validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

What I want to achieve is ordered error messages. Give the following bean class

```
public class DummyBean{

    @NotNull
    public String firstName;

    @NotNull
    public String lastName;
}
```

And using [LocalValidatorFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html) like this:

```
private Validator validator;

@Autowired
public DummyController(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
}

public void validate(DummyBean bean){
    Map<String, String> failureMessages = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    for (ConstraintViolation<DummyBean> failure : validator.validate(bean)) {
        failureMessages.put(failure.getPropertyPath().toString(), failure.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that errors messages related to property "firstName" always come first related to "lastName"?

Afaik only group sequences can be ordered but I'm hoping that maybe someone came across this problem already

Comment: This is related/identical to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11139588/132374

Answer (score 1):

You are right, if you want to enforce an order you need to use a group sequence. However, in this case validation will stop as soon as a constraint violation occurs. This means in this case you would never get constraint violation for both *firstName* and *lastName*.

Also consider that you are getting a *Set* of violations and that there is no guaranteed iteration order over a set.